# Стиль CSS для анимации открытия ветви QTreeView

Tags: css, qt, treeview

```
QTreeWidget widget;
widget.setAnimate(true);
```

При открытии parent, список дочерних элементов child раскрывается заметно глазу, а не сразу отрисовываются все элементы

```
+ parent
|--- child 1
|--- child 2
|--- child 3
|--- child 4
```

Задаем css стиль для виджета.

```
QTreeWidget {
    background-color: #007AB5;
}

QTreeWidget::item:open {
    background-color: #DDB93B;
}
```

Теперь при parent будет закрашен цветом, и при появлении дочерние элементы также окрасятся в нужный цвет. Но в промежутке, во время анимации элементы раскрашены белым цветом (фон).

Как сделать так, чтобы и в момент анимации дочерние элементы были раскрашены?

Comment: почему бы их сразу не закрасить в стилях...?

Comment: `QTreeWidget::item { `
`background-color: #007AB5;`
`}`
Так тоже самое. Расрашиваются только когда показались все элементы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему используя QStyledItemDelegate.
До этого были элементы были в виде QTreeWidgetItem с виджетами (setItemWidget()).